# QML Minimum drag/flick distance for changing item

Tags: qt, listview, qml, drag

I have a ListView in QML using theese properties :

```
ListView {
   id : list
   boundsBehaviour: Flickable.StopAtBounds
   snapMode: PathView.SnapOneItem
   highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
   highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
   ...
}
```

My problem is the following :
I'm trying to determine exactly when the drag/flick will made the list move to the next/previous item or staying on the same one when releasing the touch.

Is there a property to modify or something useful to know which behaviour will happen ?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question. The length of the drag is dependent on the point in which the drag started, the drag threshold (which can be easily found) and the delegate size, I think. What is the purpose of such specific calculation? Would you mind expand on the reason it?

Comment: This information is stored in `QGuiApplicaton` - you may get or modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for [startDragDistance](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#startDragDistance-prop) property in QApplication class, the default value of startDragDistance is 10 pixels for Windows (it depends on OS)

In order to set drag distance to 50 pixels, you can use the following line
`QApplication::setStartDragDistance(50);`